# Fast Enumeration error?

Tags: ios

Getting a warning saying that:

Collection expression type 'NSString *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count'

when trying to run the following code:

```
 NSString *proper = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"usr/share/dict/propernames"     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];


for (NSString *i in proper){
        NSLog(@"Item>%@", i);
        }
```

When I run the program I don't get any output from the NSLog statement. Anyone run into this?

Comment: How is an `NSString` a `Collection`?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler warning is trying to tell you that you cannot iterate over an `NSString` using a `for ... in ...` loop.  It is further trying to say than the reason for this is that an `NSString` is not a valid "Collection" type.  Your valid "Collection" types are things like `NSArray`, `NSSet`, and `NSDictionary`.

So if your file is supposed to contain structured data, you should parse it into something more useful than a flat `NSString`.  Something like this may give a better result:

```
NSString* temp = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"usr/share/dict/propernames"     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray* proper = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (NSString* i in proper){
    NSLog(@"Item>%@", i);
}
```

That will print each line in the file.  This assumes, of course, that your input file has one entry per line.  If it is structured some other way, then you will have to parse it differently.

Comment: This makes complete sense but still doesn't return any output. The propernames file is just a list of names in a file on all macs. Looks like the \n would be the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

After you load the file, split it into lines with componentsSeparatedByString: .

```
NSArray *lines = [proper componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; // Use the correct line ending character here
for (NSString *i in lines) {
    NSLog(@"item> %@", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear mistake u have here.
NSString* is a string object and is not a collection of characters as the string object known in C++ which is a character array.
for-in Loop need a collection to iterate within. like NSArray or NSSet.